# How to runtime control `bevy_hanabi` acceleration?

Tags: rust, bevy

I am creating a game using `bevy 0.12` and `bevy_hanabi` and am creating the visual effects for a space-themed thruster. Ideally, I would be able to chuck something in a `Query< ... >`, and update some property/attribute/data to reduce the acceleration of newly spawned particles. This way, the strength of the thrusters can be visually seen.

In previous versions, to control the thruster particle effects I simply call `mut q_spawner: Query<&mut EffectSpawner> ... q_spawner.single_mut().set_active( ... )` which worked just fine. I want more control than a simple binary 'active' or 'inactive' however.

(I'm currently looking into `CompiledParticleEffect::set_property`)